# webhelpers with some serious Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyramid, pagination

In my virtualenv, I have installed WebHelpers with some errors, but the installation process finished in the end.

When I start the Pyramid Web Application, I still get the this error:

```
  File "D:\Py3Env\lib\site-packages\webhelpers-1.3-py3.2.egg\webhelpers\paginate
.py", line 250
    raise Exception, "__getitem__ without slicing not supported"
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

The WebHelpers package is not (yet) python 3 compatible.

Python 3 has removed support for raising exceptions with a type and value. It should instead read:

```
raise Exception("__getitem__ without slicing not supported")
```

Unfortunately, there are more things in the WebHelpers source code that make porting it to Python 3 a daunting task, especially for someone new to Python.

You'll either have to switch to using Python 2 or use a different library altogether.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2015 [WebHelpers 2](http://webhelpers2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) has been released. Which is compatible with Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

## From Python 2 to Python 3

- the *WebHelpers* project is only compatible with **Python 2** and **won't** be updated to Python 3!
- as **Python 3** alternative you could use the successor *WebHelpers2* ([official website](https://webhelpers2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/))

#### About `webhelpers.paginate`

- the package `webhelpers.paginate` got completely removed from *WebHelpers2* because the author created an extra module on PyPi, simply called *Paginate* ([official website](https://webhelpers2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrate.html#webhelpers-paginate)) [[source](https://webhelpers2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrate.html#webhelpers-paginate)]

So when working with **Python 3**, just use `pip install paginate`